# Pyechonest Remix Echo Nest API Error 2: 2|API key not allowed

Tags: api, echonest

I expect that due to the migration of Echonest API to Spotify API, I'm now getting an error when I try to retrieve an `audio_analysis` object.

But I'm not sure how or where to change the API I'm calling from the Echonest API to the Spotify API.

The code is basically:

```
from echonest.remix.audio import AudioAnalysis
AudioAnalysis(str(track_md5))
```

Will pyechonest and remix still work? And if so, where do I need to make configuration changes?

I imagine I am missing something obvious.